# Multithreaded access to add, get, remove methods, using recursion and Java and a Tree structure

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, recursion, tree

I have a tree structure that I am trying to use a recursive method to add, get, or remove an item. I would like to be able to introduce a new thread for every child node that I find with an iterator. I currently pass the node into the recursive method when I call it. I would like to be able to start a thread and tell that thread to call that method. How would I do something similar to saying new thread, thread.callMethod()? I need to have a Runnable interface and a run method apparently? However this seems to complicate things much more than necessary (I already have method names). Does anyone know a good way to do this using run(..), or does anyone know a better way to do this without using run(..). Thanks.

Thank you for your answers. I had been thinking that I need to somehoe get a new instance of a node running on a new thread, but that is not the case. The node just occupies space in memory and the thread is reference to the method code that is executed on the instance living in memory (my CS 302 TA is already disagreeing with me in my head). So.. I had been thinking about enums, but I was thinking that I might somehow need to have all my nodes running on separate threads during instantiation, or else, have the methods actually written in new classes that implement runnable.

In other words,

```
public class TreeMethods implements Runnable
{
...
    run(.. node, .. params, .. enum)
    {
        switch(enum)
        case(add)
        {
             myThreadInstanceMethod(node);
        }
    ...
    }
    myThreadInstanceMethod(..) {..}
}
```

Thanks. I didn't know that I was asking this question, but you've just simplified my thread management design process greatly.

Comment: Multi-threaded & removal of data from a tree sounds like a synchronization nightmare. Also consider that too many threads won't work too well in parallel.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no synchronization. There is only one thread per instance, max. The only thing is that the thread that starts the method has to wait for all the threads that it started to complete. However, it should be waiting for a return value from each method call. Therefore, there is no need to keep context switching to it, if I can wait(), sleep(), or join() the main thread somehow, until return value "i" is actually produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it without a `Runnable` or `Callable` object.  The proper way to do what you want is to create a `Runnable` class that takes your object and calls the appropriate method on that object.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private MyObject obj;
    public MyRunnable(MyObject obj) {
       this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {
       obj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

If you need to call one of a couple methods then you can use an `enum` for this.  If you need to pass in arguments then you can add them to the constructor.

With threads, it's always recommended that you use the `Executors` class and the `ExecutorService` thread pools.  This will limit the number of threads created by your recursive algorithm and keep the thread particulars hidden.

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// or you can create an open-ended thread pool
// ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
while (recursing) {
    threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(myObject));
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra information about the Executor service. For large instances of the Tree, not utilizing the executor service might make the number of threads prohibitively large.

Comment: I was just reading through a book called "Persistence in the Enterprise: A Guide to Persistence Technologies" (2008, IBM Press). I see that you authored ORMLite. I find it interesting. I will probably be reading through the code examples and api more later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

Your runnable:

```
public class ComputeNode implements Runnable {

    private Node node;

    public ComputeNode(Node nodeToCompute) {
        this.node = nodeToCompute;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        computeOnNode(node);
    }
}
```

How to start it:

```
Runnable compute = new ComputeNode(nodeToComputeOn);
Thread t = new Thread(comute);
t.start();
```

ComputeOnNode() is your own method written somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, but calling the instance method on the node passed in was the better answer.